# Отправка POST JSON запроса на сервер Django

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django

Есть JS код для отправки данных в виде HTML form.

```
async function request(url, form, csrftoken) {
    const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken},
        body: new FormData(document.forms.namedItem(form)),
    })
    const result = await response.json()
    return result
}
```

Есть Python скрипт для обработки запроса.

```
def test_r(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.user.is_authenticated:
        user = auth.get_user(request)
        pub = BasicText.objects.create(
            date_time=datetime.now(),
            text=request.POST.get('text'),
            user_name=user,
        )

    return JsonResponse({'id': f'{pub.id}', 'date_time': pub.date_time, })
```

В данном виде сервер Django получает данные из HTML from (текст из input) и сохраняет в БД. Однако  при попытке отправить данные на сервер в виде JSON request.POST пустует. Пробовал в таком виде данные отправлять, но как я уже писал request.POST.get() не выдаёт никаких результатов. Функция request_json НЕ работает.

```
async function request_json(url, csrftoken) {
    const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
            'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken,
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            'text': 'test_data',
        }),
    })
    const result = await response.json()
    return result
}
```

Как сделать так, чтобы можно было отправлять на сервер Django POST запрос с данными JSON?
**--- PS ----**
В итоге сделал таким образом (спасибо за ответы):
JS

```
async function request(url, data, csrftoken) {
    const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken,
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
    })
    const result = await response.text()
    return result
}
async function check_username() {
    const url = '{% url "check_name_s" %}'
    const data = {'name': document.getElementById('name').value, }
    const csrftoken = '{{ csrf_token }}'
    const result = await request(url, data, csrftoken)
    console.log(result)
}
```

Python

```
from json import loads
def check_name_s(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(loads(request.body)['name'])

    return HttpResponse('hello')
```

Comment: Такой же вопрос и о _'text/plain;charset=UTF-8'_, что тоже не видно чтобы оно отображалось в request.POST.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Суть заключается в том, что в `request.POST` будут спарсены данные отправленные с типом контента `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, а если тип контента `application/json`, то получить данные отправленные клиентом можно из request.body.

код вью

```
@csrf_exempt
def ajax(request):
    print("POST:", request.POST)
    print("BODY:", request.body)
    return JsonResponse({"status": "success"})
```

отправляю запрос

```
import requests


requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/ajax/", data={"a": "b"})
```

в логе

```
POST: <QueryDict: {'a': ['b']}>
BODY: b'a=b'
```

а теперь json

```
requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/ajax/", json={"a": "b"})
```

```
POST: <QueryDict: {}>
BODY: b'{"a": "b"}'
```

т.е. тебе нужно самому десериализовать это.

```
import json


@csrf_exempt
def ajax(request):
    print("POST:", request.POST)
    print("BODY:", json.loads(request.body))
    return JsonResponse({"status": "success"})
```